# BizTalk Error in event log on running request in SOAPUI

Tags: c#, xml, soapui, biztalk

This is the error encountered in Event log of BizTalk Admin

> xlang/s engine event log entry: Uncaught exception (see the 'inner
>   exception' below) has suspended an instance of service
>   'orchestration.AsyncOrchestration(ebb0442e-bff4-cd1c-f5dc-aff7c5086e57)'.
>   The service instance will remain suspended until administratively
>   resumed or terminated. If resumed the instance will continue from its
>   last persisted state and may re-throw the same unexpected exception.
>   InstanceId: 50fc5f8b-c9b9-44e1-9781-2a1391c145ec Shape name:
>   Expression_1 ShapeId: ddfccde4-3444-47c4-977d-228e66ffaae6 Exception
>   thrown from: segment 1, progress 17 Inner exception: Resolution of the
>   dependency failed, type =
>   "BizTalkComponents.Interface.ISsoSettingsReader", name = "(none)".
>   Exception occurred while: while resolving. Exception is:
>   InvalidOperationException - The current type,
>   BizTalkComponents.Interface.ISsoSettingsReader, is an interface and
>   cannot be constructed.

Are you missing a type mapping?

Answer (score 0):

First, this has noting to do with SOAPUI or any specific client.

It seems that your deployment process has failed to include the SSO lookup components that are called in the failing Orchestration.

So, whichever set of component the app is using must be installed on the server.